# Tricky equivalence between the principle of mathematical induction (PMI) and the principle of transfinite induction (PTI) in Halmos's book

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In §17 Halmos defines the principle of transfinite induction (PTI) as follows:

> suppose that $S$ is a subset of a well ordered set $X$, and suppose that whenever an element $x$ of $X$ is such that the entire initial segment $s(x)$ is included in $S$, then $x$ itself belongs to $S$; the **principle of transfinite induction** asserts that under these circumstances we must have $S = X$. Equivalently: if the presence in a set of all the strict predecessors of an element always implies the presence of the element itself, then the set must contain everything.

In the next paragraph he says:

> The present statement when applied to $\omega$ is easily proved to be equivalent to the principle of mathematical induction

In §12 Halmos defines the principle of mathematical induction (PMI) as a property of $\omega$, that is, of the intersection of all successor sets:

> if $S \subset \omega$, if $0 \in S$, and if $n^+ \in S$ whenever $n \in S$, then $S = \omega$

whose property is a consequence of the existence of $\omega$ and therefore a consequence of the axiom of infinity or the existence of a successor set. So in this context, wouldn't it be vacuous to say that both principles are equivalent when proving the principle of mathematical induction implies assuming the existence of a successor set? And therefore the principle of mathematical induction is true regardless of any hypothesis that may be assumed.

I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So in this context, wouldn't it be vacuous to say that both principles are equivalent when proving the principle of mathematical induction implies assuming the existence of a successor set? And therefore the principle of mathematical induction is true regardless of any hypothesis that may be assumed.
>
> I'm missing something?

It's common practice in the literature and in day-to-day (ordinary, outside of logic) informal math-talk to say two (or more) *provable* statements are 'equivalent' in the non-technical sense that "[any can be easily obtained from any other](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190587/is-there-a-simple-direct-proof-of-the-open-mapping-theorem-from-the-uniform-boun)". It happens with some 'foundational' results in real analysis as, say, the Intermediate Value Theorem, the Heine-Borel compactness theorem of the/any interval, and the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, or in functional analysis with the open mapping theorem and friends, or in calculus with the inverse function theorem and the implicit function theorem, or in topology with [Brouwer's fixed-point theorem and Sperner's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#Equivalent_results)

As you noticed, stricly speaking, this would be trivial/meaningless from the point of view of any logic strong enough to contain/prove the scheme

$\varphi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \varphi)$

but *sometimes* it just happens that the statements refered to as equivalent are ones for which the more reasonable notion of 'equivalence' as "there exists a proper/weaker subtheory which does not prove either statement, but proves the two implications between them" actually applies: most famously the trio consisting of the Axiom of Choice, the Well-Ordering Theorem, and Zorn's Lemma, all not provable in ZF

It also sometimes happen that some such called 'equivalences' turn out to be false in rather precise senses: when formulated in [second-order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_arithmetic) both the Intermediate Value Theorem and Sperner's lemma are provable in the weak 'recursive comprehension' theory, while Heine-Borel and Brouwer's FPT require a stricly strong theory ('weak König's lemma'), and Bolzano-Weierstrass require a stronger one still ('arithmetic comprehension') (take a look at Simpson's *Subsystems of second order arithmetic* for all of this). That these statements can *even appear* to be equivalent in that informal sense maybe be due to the set theory most people use being too strong to notice any distinction

tldr: people often say stuff that makes intuitive sense to them without any formal backing, sometimes it's possible to investigate such stuff, and it may or may not agree with the informal picture

Comment: This answer was enlightening, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add this alternative answer as a possible interpretation of what Halmos wants us to prove.

After rereading the paragraph several times I think I made a mistake by not quoting it completely, this is how the text really continues after the definition of the PTI:

> A few remarks are in order before we look at the proof. The statement of the ordinary principle of mathematical induction differs from that of transfinite induction in two conspicuous respects. One: the latter, instead of passing to each element from its predecessor, passes to each element from the set of all its predecessors. Two: in the latter there is no assumption about a starting element (such as zero). The first difference is important: an element in a well ordered set may fail to have an immediate predecessor. The present statement when applied to $\omega$ is easily proved to be equivalent to the principle of mathematical induction; that principle, however, when applied to an arbitrary well ordered set, is not equivalent to the principle of transfinite induction. To put it differently: the two statements are in general not equivalent to each other; their equivalence in $\omega$ is a happy but special circumstance.

And continues:

> Here is an example. Let $X$ be $\omega ^ +$, i.e., $X = \omega \cup \{ \omega \}$. Define order in $X$ by ordering the elements of $\omega$ as usual and by requiring that $n < \omega$ for all $n$ in $\omega$. The result is a well ordered set. Question: does there exist a proper subset $S$ of $X$ such that $0 \in S$ and such that $n + 1 \in S$ whenever $n \in S$? Answer: yes, namely $S = \omega$.

So inspired by that example and this warning:

> The first difference is important: an element in a well ordered set may fail to have an immediate predecessor.

I think Halmos wants us to prove the equivalence between PTI applied to $\omega$ together with the assumption that all elements of $\omega$ have an immediate predecessor. Which makes sense since these quotes are found within the section titled "Well Ordering".

So my interpretation of Halmos's intention is that he wants to state that the only thing that distinguishes $\omega$ from all well-ordered sets is the fact that all its elements have an immediate predecessor. And that was the equivalence he wanted us to prove.